# service exeption when creating entity manager factory

Tags: java, mysql

I tried building my project today and am having problems connecting to MySQL. I am getting an exception : org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] when I try to create my entity manager factory. It was working fine yesterday. I have checked MySql is running and have tried to restart computer but nothing has worked.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="VictoryPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.stevie.memberfx.model.HouseholdEntity</class>
    <class>com.stevie.memberfx.model.MemberEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/victorydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="stephen"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ozzie2014"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my code to create the entity manager factory:

```
public class JpaUtil {

private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

static {
    try {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("VictoryPU");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.out.println("Initial EntityManagerFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to change mysql driver to version 5 and change the driver name in your persistence.xml file to the old name com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: That Worked! Thank you